# Why is cross-correlation not defined in a normalized sense?

Tags: correlation

When correlation is defined in systems and signals, as well as in the statistical sense, it is defined as a normalized measure with respect to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

$\space$

In systems and signals, correlation is defined as

$$\rho = \frac{ \langle x(t), \space y(t) \rangle}{\| x(t)\|\|y(t)\|} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{E_xE_y}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)y^*(t)dt$$

Here, the inner product is normalized by dividing it by the square root of the energies, or the norms, of the two signals in question. The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for this case is stated as

$$ |\langle x(t), \space y(t)\rangle| \leq \| x(t)\|\|y(t)\|$$

$\space$

In statistics, correlation is defined as

$$\rho_{xy} = \frac{Cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_x\sigma_y}$$

Here, the covariance is normalized by dividing it by the square root of the variances, or the standard deviations, of the two random variables in question. The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for this case is stated as

$$|Cov(X,Y)| \leq \sigma_x\sigma_y$$

$\space$

So, it seems as if there is a universal trend for defining correlation in a normalized sense. That is until we get to cross-correlation. For some reason cross-correlation is defined as

$$ \psi(\tau) = \langle x(t), \space y(t-\tau) \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t)y^*(t-\tau)dt $$

Here, the cross-correlation is simply the time-shifted inner product. No normalization has been applied in this definition.

$\space$

**So, why** do we define correlation in a normalized sense across the board, but when it comes to its' extended time delayed version, **cross-correlation, we "forget" to normalize it all of a sudden?**

Comment: It's just words.  Don't make too much of it.

Comment: It's not just words. It's definitions which allow for mental associations between concepts. The more clearly and consistently they are defined the more fluently we can think about them.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but covariance uses subtraction of the means, while cross-correlation does not.

Comment: @herb steinberg That is in the statistical sense, but in the signal sense no means are subtracted. In the statistical sense this is fine since the variances, which are used to normalize the covariance, also have mean subtraction.

Comment: You are **never** going to get an acceptable answer to this question.

Comment: @Somos I can only hope.

Comment: I believe the answer lies in the background of these terms.  Auto-correlation and cross-correlation are terms used in signal theory when discussing the relationship between a signal at different times or between two different signals, any of which are corrupted by noise.  In these situations we are often working with time averages as well as statistical.  (continued)

Comment: (continuation) On the other hand variance and co-variance are terms used in probability theory and statistics concerning random variables (no time dependence usually).  Correlation here is used for making the quantities of interest non-dimensional.  As you can see these terms in both contexts describe similar relationships, but the things involved are different  I hope this clarifies it..

Comment: @Gustav The description of $\rho$ at the beginning of your question is somewhat in error, in that t is no longer an argument, since the expressions are averaged over time.

Comment: @herb steinberg Cross-correlation and auto-correlation are also defined in the statistical sense. With regards to the time not being an argument, I did not define ρ as a time dependent function. When showing the time variable in the expressions it is merely to make it easier for the reader to distinguish between scalars and functions.

Comment: Cross-correlation and auto-correlation are statistical functions of time.  Correlation is not (usually) a function.  Unfortunately these terms developed in different contexts, so the net result is that the signal theory term is not normalized while the probability theory term is.

Comment: @herb steinberg I'll accept that as an answer. It would have been nice if everything was perfectly consistent, but unfortunately that is an unrealistic expectation (no pun intented).